# Google Sheet problem: How to add the number of people on standby (number on a cell) while ignoring the number of people deployed (In between 2 cells)?

Tags: google-sheets, sum

I am Alex from a traffic control management company. I am having trouble this small issue I had on Google Sheet.

Basically I need to count the total of officers on standby (pure number on a cell, in between empty cells) from officers deployed (pure numbers or numbers with text, in between 2 string cells).

[Traffic officers management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRO9G.jpg)

I used =ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(F2:F28,{1, 2, 3}))), but it only counted the cells that have numbers 1, 2 or 3 in it. Result is 5 as it counted the number of cells and not the total.

The result that I want is 6 (2+1+3) which is the total number of officers on standby. But the above formula I have used gave me the result of 5 as it counted the cells with only numbers.

Do let me know if there is a solution to this, thank you!

Comment: Hi Alex! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain what the desired output is?

Comment: @Mark Hi there Mark, thank you for the welcome. Ohhhh my desired output is 6. Which is the sum of the cells, the pure numbers in between 2 empty cells that are added together. The example image is in the link text 'Traffic officers management'.

Comment: It will much easier for everyone that you provide a sample of a sheet with dummy data which represent you have done and what is expected, you will get a quicker response

Comment: @Nabnub Ahhhhhh sure, let me see if I can add it here hahha Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(,A2:A,lambda(a,c,a+if(and(isnumber(c),offset(c,-1,)="",offset(c,1,)=""),c,)))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my, you are a genius! Awesome, the formula works! Really really appreciate the time spent working on this solution  Please do have an awesome blessed day   